# Swift: Access Parent ViewController Segue from UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, segue

## What I have so far

I have a view controller ViewController1 which has 2 segues, one that goes to ViewController2 and one that comes back.

The segue from vc2 - vc1 is called "**ViewC2toViewC1Segue**"

On ViewController2 I have a UIScrollView that loads in two new viewcontrollers and allows me to scroll left or right to view them.

All these work fine, the data shows ok and everything displays nicely. However, On one of these subviews I want to be able to display an option to go back to ViewController1.

in my naivety I tried just using:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewC2toViewC1Segue", sender: self)
```

I hope this image helps explain:

[image]

## The Problem

These two viewcontrollers that are loaded in the UIScrollView or not on the main storyboard so I can not CTRL and DRAG.

## Question

How do I access the segue (ViewC2toViewC1Segue) of the view controller (ViewController2) that is holding the UIScrollView from one of UIScrollViews Child view containers.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you add both UIScrollViews child view controllers as actually child view controllers of ViewController2 so they can access their parent and performSegue from there?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with a delegate protocol. Your parent view controller would be the delegate of the child. When the button is pushed on the child, it messages its delegate (the parent, who has the scroll view), and the parent handles scrolling to the other view controller.

---

In your ChildViewController file, you want to do 3 things:

1. Define the delegate protocol. This is a set of functions that the delegate object needs to implement.
2. Add a `delegate` property to the ChildVC class. This allows the ChildVC to call functions on the delegate.
3. Call the delegate function when the button is pressed

The protocol declaration would look something like this

`protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func childViewControllerDidSelectBack(childViewController: ChildViewController)
}`

The `delegate` variable declaration would look like:

`class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate?
}`

To call the delegate function, in your button handler code simply write:

`delegate.childViewControllerDidSelectBack(self)`

---

In your ParentViewController file, you want to do 3 things:

1. Set yourself as the delegate for the ChildVC
2. Declare that you conform to the ChildVCDelegate protocol
3. Implement the delegate protocol methods

To set yourself as the delegate, whenever you instantiate the child VC, do something like:

`childVC.delegate = self`

To declare that you conform to the protocol, make your class definition look like:

`class ParentViewController: UIViewController, ChildViewControllerDelegate`

Lastly, you need to implement the protocol function

`func childViewControllerDidSelectBack(childViewController: ChildViewController){
    // code to scroll the scrollview
    }
}`

---

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I am a little noobie when it comes to swift. Would you possibly be able to provide a little more detail? I am confused how to call this protocol from the button click etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use notification approach here.

- On button click of one of your ViewController (in scrollview) post
  notification.
- Add observer in ViewController2's viewDidLoad method.
- Go back to ViewController1 in selector method.

===================================================

```
//ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(navigateToViewController1) name:@"navigateToViewController1" object:nil];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)navigateToViewController1 {
   //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   OR
   // perform segue
}



//In button click event of your viewcontroller inside scrollview.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"navigateToViewController1" object:nil];
```